Calculating TD($\lambda$) returns, reinforcement learning
I am having some trouble with answering the following question:
A rat is involved in an experiment. It experiences one episode. At the first step it hears a bell. At the second step it sees a light. At the third step it both hears a bell and sees a light. It then receives some food, worth +1 reward, and the episode terminates on the fourth step. All other rewards were zero. The experiment is undiscounted ($\gamma = 1$).
Approximate the state-value function by a linear combination of these features with two parameters: $b · bell(s) + l · light(s)$. If $b = 2$ and $l = −2$, write down the sequence of $\lambda$-returns $v_t^\lambda$ corresponding to this episode, for $\lambda = 0.5$.
The provided answer is this:
$v^\lambda_1 = 0.5 (−2 + 0.5×0 + 0.5×1) = −3/4$
$v^\lambda_2 = 0.5 (0 + 1×1) = 1/2$
$v^\lambda_3 = 0.5 (2×1) = 1$
However, these are my calculations:
$v^\lambda_1 = 0.5 (.5^0×−2 + .5^1×0 + .5^2×1) = 0.875$
$v^\lambda_2 = 0.5 (.5^0×0 + .5^1×1) = 1/4$
$v^\lambda_3 = 0.5 (.5^0×1) = 1/2$
Any help is appreciated!
Edit:
These are the functions used:
$v^{(n)}_t = r_{t+1} +\gamma r_{t+2}+\dots+\gamma^{n−1} r_{t+n} + \gamma^n V_{(s_{t+n})} $
$v^\lambda _t = (1−\lambda)\sum_{n=1}^\infty \lambda^{n−1} v^{(n)}_t$
bell state = $[1 \ \ 0]^T$
light state = $[0 \  \ 1]^T$
bell and light state = $[1 \ \ 1]^T$

Instead of writing "TD ... question", can you please just ask your specific question in the title? Thanks

Could you clarify what formula you are applying in your calculations please, by adding its algebraic form? Most likely you have the wrong formula for the TD plus linear state value approximation, but you could also be making incorrect substitutions.

@NeilSlater I've added the formulas

Thanks. I don't see the linear approximator in your formulae? Typically the trace works directly on the approximator's state description vector.

That's not what I meant. The trace doesn't operate on $v$ directly, it operates on $x$, the state description vector - sometimes noted as $\Phi(x)$. So you will end up with an eligibility trace vector that does not represent a specific state, that you will multiply by $[2, -2]$ to getthe current value approximation. You also have to decide between replacing traces and accumulating traces.
